# Prisma GraphQL API: "Cannot read property 'create' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, graphql, prisma

my very simple GraphQL API which is connected to a PostgreSQL running on a docker container works fine.
As soon as I try to add a new field it stops working:
I try to add the field "content"

my typeDefs:

```
const typeDefs = gql`

  type Book {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    content: String

  }
  
  type Query {  
    books: [Book!]! 
  }

  type Mutation {   
    createBook(name: String, content: String): Book!
    
  } 
`
```

Here are my resolvers:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    books: (parent, args) => {
      return prisma.book.findMany()
    }, 
  },
 
  Mutation: { 
    createBook: (parent, args) => {
      return prisma.book.create({
        data: {
          name: args.name,
          content: args.content
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my schema.prisma file:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Book {
  id   Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String?
  content String?
}
```

Without the "content" field everything works fine, as soon as I add it it throws the following error as soon as I try to query the API:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot read property 'create' of undefined",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createBook"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined",
            "    at Object.createBook (/Users/macpro/prisma-graphql-digitalocean/src/schema.js:36:26)",
            "    at field.resolve (/Users/macpro/prisma-graphql-digitalocean/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/utils/schemaInstrumentation.js:52:26)",
            "    at resolveField (/Users/macpro/prisma-graphql-digitalocean/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:464:18)",
            "    at /Users/macpro/prisma-graphql-digitalocean/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:261:18",
            "    at /Users/macpro/prisma-graphql-digitalocean/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/promiseReduce.js:23:10",
            "    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)",
            "    at promiseReduce (/Users/macpro/prisma-graphql-digitalocean/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/promiseReduce.js:20:17)",
            "    at executeFieldsSerially (/Users/macpro/prisma-graphql-digitalocean/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:258:37)",
            "    at executeOperation (/Users/macpro/prisma-graphql-digitalocean/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:236:55)",
            "    at executeImpl (/Users/macpro/prisma-graphql-digitalocean/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:116:14)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

Here is the query:

```
mutation{
  createBook(name: "Yess", content: "Test"){
    content
  }
}
```

I am so frustrated, how can such an easy thing not work?

Comment: The error says that `prisma.book` is `undefined`. Can you try regenerating the prisma client using `npx prisma generate` and see if it helps? Also double check some weird chance if you renamed the model to something other than `Book` in your Prisma schema.

Comment: @TasinIshmam `npx prisma generate` was helpful for me. Thanks!

Comment: That's awesome, welcome!  @Ryan